# Need a really simple navigation controller with a table view inside a tab bar controller

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have an app with a tab bar controller (2 tabs).  In one tab view controller, a button leads to an alert window.  I want one button of the alert window to call a table view containing possible answers.  I want that table view to have a `done` button and a `title`.  I think that means a navigation controller has to be used.  But most everything I can find on navigation controllers assumes a much more complicated situation. Here's part of the alert window logic:

```
-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

{ 
    if (buttonIndex == 2) {
        AnswersViewController *aVC = [[AnswersViewController alloc] init];
        [self presentViewController:aVC
                           animated:YES
                         completion:NULL];    
    }
}
```

And `AnswersViewController` looks like this:

```
@interface AnswersViewController : UITableViewController
@end

@implementation AnswersViewController

- (id) init
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    return self;
}


- (id) initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    return [self init];   

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

}

@end
```

This code all works as expected (an empty red `UITableView` appears).

Two questions I guess: 1.  Is there a simple modification to what I have that can give me a `done` button and `title` in my table view?  2.  If I have to go to a navigation controller (probably), how can I make a bare-bones navigation controller with a `done` button and `title` and embed the table view within it?  Oh, and I want to do this programatically.  And I think I prefer the `done` button and `title` to be in the navigation bar, no tool bar desired. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

To get what you are looking for, you do need to use a UINavigationController. That will provide the UINavigationBar where you can display a title and also buttons.

To implement this with a UINavigationController, you want to do smoothing like this (assuming you are using ARC, so you don't need to worry about memory management):

```
-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

{ 
    if (buttonIndex == 2) {
        AnswersViewController *aVC = [[AnswersViewController alloc] init];

        //Make our done button
        //Target is this same class, tapping the button will call dismissAnswersViewController:
        aVC.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissAnswersViewController:)];

       //Set the title of the view controller
       aVC.title = @"Answers";

        UINavigationController *aNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aVC];
        [self presentViewController:aNavigationController
                       animated:YES
                     completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

Then you would also implement `- (void)dismissAnswersViewController:(id)sender` in the same class as the UIAlertView delegate method (based on the implementation I have here).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed.  For completeness sake, the autoreleases weren't needed, and `initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone` should be `initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone`. Should the aVC.* lines be over in the `AnswersViewController` class?

Comment: Ah you  must be using ARC. :-) They can be in either location. If you want a different title for different cases, then you would leave it here, otherwise you can move it into the `AnswersViewController` class in `viewDidLoad:`